# Accessing "Request" object properties using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

we are developing a web application using MVC3 and Jquery. we have a situation where we need to check the request is authenticated (@Request.IsAuthenticated) using Jquery.  what is the best way to do that using Jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a helper action on one of the controllers or maybe on a Base controller and return a `ContentResult` (with a value of `true` or `false`). Use jquery's ajax() function to perform asynchronous GET request to the server side controller action.

If you can afford to have the Javascript code inside the view then you can simply do

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
...do Javascript...
```